# What is the meaning of the IDs shown when a Docker image is pulled?

Tags: docker, docker-image

When pulling a Docker image from DockerHub, the CLI shows a few progress bars, each with a different ID:

```
➜  docker pull training/sinatra
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from training/sinatra
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete
6e71c809542e: Downloading [============>                       ]  17.3 MB/67.48 MB
d196a7609355: Download complete
08f6dff5acea: Download complete
ce65532003d0: Downloading [==============================>     ] 19.24 MB/21.22 MB
54bcaa4d1a10: Downloading [=====>                              ] 25.39 MB/62.67 MB
8572ad96f6e1: Waiting
```

When the download completes, none of these IDs appears to be the downloaded image id:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY               TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
...
training/webapp          latest              6fae60ef3446        16 months ago       348.8 MB
training/sinatra         latest              49d952a36c58        2 years ago         447 MB
```

**What do the IDs that are shown during the download process stand for?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: The IDs you were seen when pulling an image is "digest", which is an SHA256 hash for each image layers. The image ID appears in your local image list is also a "digest", that digest actually represents an SHA256 hash of the image's JSON configuration object.

Answer (score 1):

Those things being pulled are the layers. Each image is made up of multiple layers, each layer has an ID. The image also has an ID. If you do `docker images -a` (for all) then you should see the other pulled IDs in the list.

Comment: Does each layer stands for a line in a Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

Those are the layers. Images are composed of other images. All the images represent the layers of the "main image". For example, when you create a new image with a Dockerfile, then every new line in your Dockerfile creates a new layer.

See the official documentation for further information about [images and layers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/).